# how to link my svn library using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dependencies, cocoapods

I am new to manage library dependencies in Objective-C projects.

I need to know *how to link a library* in my svn.

link :svn:`//ibrahim@svn.xxxx.info/development/iOS/myFoundation/here_Are_the_.{h/m}'`

I only know how Specifies a dependency of the projects on Github.

Ex from Terminal :

1-open -e Podfile

2-dependency 'ASIHTTPRequest'

3-pod install myproj.xcodeproj/

Any idea for svn will be great.

Comment: Not sure svn is supported at the moment. I tried getting a custom spec repo working with CVS and it didn't go so well. The pull commands are slightly different between git/svn/cvs. My guess is they will need to support other types on the back end to make it work.